# Docker container fails with an exception, but Airflow marks docker_operator task as passed

Tags: docker, airflow

I am running a model inside a Docker container in Airflow using Docker Operator. Whenever the model fails with an exception, the docker container is getting terminated with errors in the logs. But Airflow is marking the Docker Operator task which ran the model as passed.

I expect Airflow to fail the Docker task and as well as the DAG whenever the model doesn't run successfully. Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: What is the exit code of the container?

Comment: @PirateNinjas the container exit code is 0

Comment: Could you maybe elaborate a bit more about how you're running the model? If the container exits with code zero, then the task exited normally. Presumably your model exit code is not in the same thread as your main process. If you can share some code snippets I can try and dive a bit deeper, otherwise I'm just guessing!

Comment: Commenting in order to find answer myself.